# How to run Typescript files on Server in background?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, server

I have a NodeJS application which has only **typescript** files in it, no js files. I want to run in on my server in the background.

How can I archive that?

I tried using the npm package called [`forever`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) but it only works with js files as it doesn't understand the typescript code.

Comment: You need to compile the typescript files into javascript.

Comment: You don't run Typescript directly.  you transpile it  to Javascript and run that.

Comment: @Ceres how can i do that?

Comment: @jfriend00 how can i do that?

Comment: It is all spelled out here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/ and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter#typescript-node-starter,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `forever` in combination with `ts-node`.

Here is a link to the npm package [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)

I would suggest using the following command:

`forever start -v -c ts-node app.ts`

Where `-v/--verbose` is for turning on the verbose messages from Forever.

And `-c` is the COMMAND to execute which is default is node

Comment: works like a charm! Thank you. What does the -v and -c mean

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with `ts-node@10.9.1` and `forever@4.0.3`.

Comment: The only problem, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to install ts-node globally?

Answer (score 0):

This question is so old and [forever now discourages to use it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).

> For new installations we encourage you to use pm2 or nodemon

Here is a quick tutorial on how to run your Typescript project as a background process.

Install PM2 globally:

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

Build your sources with Typescript default config:

```
tsc
```

You will have a new directory dist that contains your js files.

```
pm2 start dist/app.js
```

Bonus: you can monitor your app with the following command.

```
pm2 monit
```

Answer (score 0):

first use
`npm install -g ts-node`
then use
`forever start -v -c ts-node app.ts`
it shuld start now

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The two *production* quality recommendations I would make are:

1. Turn it into a docker container
2. Write a systemd service

Those are by far the best options. If for some reason this doesn't work:

1. pm2
2. supervisord